# How to send notification to the user

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an app in the google play and now i want to upload new version my question is how to make notification  in the app that say their is a new version  can you help me please

Comment: When your app is updated and approved on playstore, the users will see a notification from playstore also that tells that a new  version of an app is available. However it depends on the notification settings of those users but it is on by default. If you want a notification your app also then please tell us more about your app. Does your app communicate with a server or is it an offline app?

Comment: its an offline app

Comment: For offline app you can simply rely on playstore for sending notification to users about updates available. Playstore does that unless users decide not to get this notificaiton. Because all other solutions will require you to make network calls and you would unnecessarily end up adding unwanted network permissions to your app and some other network code that would increase size of your binary, would also result in occasional errors. I would advice you to rely on playstore to notify users of new version.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some *notification managing* on your app's client side.

Some mechanism that **compares the latest app version extracted from the push notification and compare it with user's actual app version**.

When releasing your app to Google Play, always store in some *shared preferences* (for example) your actual application version, that later will be compared with latest.

Another option, is to ask some server the latest version, every time the user opens your application.

Comment: thanks for replying @alexsimo  can you gave me an example by code